# How to download files from workfront

Tags: ruby-on-rails, download, workfront-api

I have integrated Workfront APIs. I need to download files from my Workfront account using API.

```
https://api-cl01.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/v5.0/document/search?fields=downloadURL
```

Using above URL, I am able to get file download URL, Which seems line as follows :

`{ "downloadURL": "/document/download?ID=575a934000474c7938f129f536139952" }`

But, I don't know how to download it.

Comment: Did you get this to work ?

Comment: Nope, I haven't found any solution for this

Answer (score 1):

When downloading files, use the API to establish a session key. You can do this by either logging in with a username and password, or by running the login function with no password, but including an API key instead. This will have the effect of logging you in as whatever username you entered (handy if you need to make changes on behalf of some user via API).

Once you have a session established, just use cURL or something similar to get the download link of the document. Link will be something like https://{yoursubdomain}.attask-ondemand.com/document/download?versionID=57c8d8da00b7cb921ff8c9f6b59705c3&ID=57c8d8da00b7cb911bc3aace5d332da9

I just checked and you only need ID in the URL. It appears it will return the latest version if you omit versionID.